# Two Way Binding in Angular.js 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm new on Angular 2, either Angular 1.

I watched youtube tutorials about angular 2, but I got stuck because I wonder why the data is not changed automatically when I edited string. the code is below .

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'shopping-list',
    template:
        `<ul>
<li *ngFor="#shoppingListItem of shoppingListItems" 
(click)="onItemClicked(shoppingListItem)">{{shoppingListItem}}</li>
</ul>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">`
})


export class shoppingListComponent{

    public shoppingListItems = ['Milk', 'Bread', 'Sugar'];
    public selectedItem = "";
    public onItemClicked(shoppingListItem){
        this.selectedItem = shoppingListItem
    }
}
```

This code from youtube,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ_5des_6_c

At 14:55, the author say "that is because here we get plain string, so not 2 way binding, let's make it to JavaScript Object". But I don't know why it is related with plain string. Is that 2 way binding on Angular2 works only JavaScript Object? I don't think so, How can I understand it?

Comment: Strings (all primitives) are immutable.

Comment: @dfsq But this http://plnkr.co/edit/R3UX5qDaUqFO2VYR0UzH?p=preview also is a string. its 2 way binding works well. any I missed??

Comment: The thing is that you set `selecteItem` equal to the string. But there is no connection between this value and `shoppingListItems`. `selecteItem` is just a copy of the sting from the array. So you update ngModel, but it can't affect  the original value in the array.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks... now I understand it.